# Integrating MS CRM 2011 with Outlook 2016

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, outlook-2016

Please can you let me know it is possible to integrate MSCRM 2011 with Outlook 2016? There are couple of links where some says they do support while other says they do not support.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is yes for CRM 2011 >= UR18.

According to [Technet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh699818(v=crm.5).aspx), CRM for Outlook 2011 requires one of the following:

> - Microsoft Office 2016
> - Microsoft Office 2013
> - Microsoft Office 2010
> - 2007 Microsoft Office system SP2
> - Microsoft Office 2003 SP3

Additionally the following limitations are listed for Office 2016:

> Office 2016 compatibility requires Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2011 Update
>   Rollup 18 or later update rollup.
>
> Click-to-Run installed versions of
>   Office 2016 are not compatible with Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2011.

Comment: "Click-to-Run installed versions of Office 2016 are not compatible with Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2011." ...didnt got this point?

Comment: The system which I am working on uses Update rollup 13.What it takes to upgrade to update rollup 18+

Comment: I have couple of Querys here:
1. How do we upgrade from the rollup 13 to 18, will it  be direct deployment of UR 18 or we need to install 14,15 etc.. 2. Is it safe to upgrade?
3. Any other requirement for UR18 that you didnt mention